# Getting friend facebook Checkin information

Tags: facebook, checkin

I wanted to get friends_checkin information in a App, i requested "user_checkins", "friends_checkins" to get the access token.

When i make a request for me/checkins i get an empty dataset back.

So I thought may be I am doing something wrong in the code so I went to graphapiexplorer on facebook and tried there
First i requested an access token for the same permissions and then tried it, there still i get an empty dataset
{  "data": [  ]}

I have checked (atleast what ever I could) on the account (I am using mine and my friend's account for verification) that my friend's account has all possible settings to share checkin information.

So now my questions are
Is it possible to get Friends checkin information (facebook help seems to say yes)?
What settings are there to allow a friend to see my checkin information or vice versa?
Are there examples which do the same?

Edit: A follow up question:
If the above is not possible, one alternate I was thinking was to get a list of friends and then for each friend get their checkin information. Would this work? If yes then how, because a simple re query with //checkins did not work (obviously it will not, because the friend has not logged in and allowed my app to get that information). What are the other ways I can make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a fql query to the graph api. In the graph api explorer, try the following query (this might take a while to run depending on how many friends you have)

```
fql?q=select tagged_uids,page_id from checkin WHERE author_uid in(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

More info about the available fields can be found here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/

Comment: This is definitely helpful, probably more useful than the way I was using. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello After many more research i got the result by using me/locations its locations also put s because if you use location i will provide home location and if use locations it will provide all checkins data i thing its facebook bug  thx